# Swift & Objective-C project - generated -Swift.h error - Cannot find interface declaration for UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, language-interoperability

I've got a project using the Swift generated Bridging Header and have the project set up correctly (no spaces in Names, Uses Modules, pre-declaring Swift classes in my .mm file, Deleting derived data, doing a clean rebuild etc...). The Bridging Header is being generated fine, but the automatically generated -Swift.h has errors in it. What's even worse, those errors are on the generated (in project creation - Swift) versions of AppDelegate and ViewController which would normally compile fine. The errors in the -Swift.h are:

- `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>`
  **>> Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIResponder', superclass
  of 'AppDelegate'**
  **>> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UIApplicationDelegate'**
- `@interface ViewController : UIViewController`
  **>> Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIViewController', superclass
  of 'ViewController'**

I've searched Stack Overflow and the net and can't find any answer that addresses this particular issue. Has anyone else had this? Or, is there a way I can mark my AppDelegate and ViewController classes so Xcode **doesn't** try and create Objective-C stubs for those Swift classes as I don't actually need them?

Answer (score 20):

Just add

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

before

```
#import <YourProject-Swift.h>
```

in .mm file. for me it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: You saved my day. +=1

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem and discovered that..

-Swift.h only work best with Objective-C, not Objective-C++ (.mm)

So I use the Objective-C class to connect with the Swift class.  Also You can always load your Objective-C++ class in your Objective-C class.

Comment: I am having this issue with CoreData :(

Comment: for CoreData, I use Objective C to handle the CoreData model class.  Feel free to look at my example database app on github
[SweeneyApps Link at Github](https://github.com/sweeneyapps/coredataSwiftExample)

Comment: It works for me with Objective-C++ in Xcode 13.

Answer (score 4):

Try to import UIKit/UIKit.h into bridging header file.

Comment: For me it did not help to import `UIKit/UIKit.h` in `Project-Swift.h`, but doing so in my actual Objective C header file did the trick.

Comment: If it doesn't work. Try to import UIKit/UIKit.h into bridging header file.

Comment: You shouldn't alter the `-Swift.h` file as this is auto-generated, and the issue will hit you back, once Xcode re-creates this file.

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn’t play very well with Objective-C++. Since I need to interface with C++, I tend to write an Objective-C++ class MyClass_CPP containing just the interface with C++, then an Objective-C subclass MyClass that can play nicely with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the latest working answer so far (2023).

In my case, this has happened before, when I was working on a chat feature in my Objective-C project.

And now, I want to subclass `AVPlayerViewController` in Swift, and use that Swift subclass in my Objective-C file.

One way to fix this is to have an Objective-C subclass to subclass the module class of any iOS framework (e.g. AVKit). Then use that Objective-C subclass as the superclass of your Swift subclass.