# Cannot find interface declaration in myproject-swift.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, header, xlpagertabstrip

I'
m using `XLPagerTabStrip` pod in my project,

i have a bridging header for other purposes to integrate from swift to objective c `myproject-swift.h`

**i cant build the project and this error always pops:**

> Cannot find interface declaration for
>   'ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController', superclass of
>   'ParentViewController'

[image]

This is my Controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tabStripStyle()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
   }
```

I have seen this issue everywhere posted but its not yet answered here:  ['Cannot find interface declaration' in auto-generated Swift bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447327/cannot-find-interface-declaration-in-auto-generated-swift-bridging-header)

Bugs in swift  [SR-805](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-805) [SR-5398](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5398)

Comment: Is myproject-swift.h a bridging header that shows up in your project and contains Objective-C declarations for use by Swift?  Or is it Xcode-generated interface header (not listed as part of your project) containing declarations for use by Objective-C, so it can make use of your Swift code?  If it's the latter, then it should not be called a bridging header.  Just trying to understand your use of terminology.

Comment: its an auto generated interface which contains Objective-C declarations for use by Swift @AnatoliP

Comment: Where's `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController` declared, and how?

Comment: @Cristik its from a pod

Comment: And how about `ParentViewController`? How is that declared in Swift? Please add all the relevant information into the question, this will make it easier for people to understand the problem.

Comment: The `ParentViewController` class  conform from `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController ` ill edit the question right now, please make sure to check it @Cristik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You needed to import the -Swift.h for for both the framework and the app target

For Example :

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "XLPagerTabStrip-Swift.h"
    #import "RealmSwift-Swift.h"
    ...... // Add all frameworks, subclasses, and dependance ios frameworks
    #import  "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

You can read this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) How to import file header and check paths

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: This didn't work for me with a Swift package, but after adding -fmodules and -fcxx-modules to my build settings, I was able to use "@import MySwiftPackage;" before the -Swift.h bridging header import, and that DID work.

Answer (score 0):

I had error "Cannot find interface declaration for 'CLLocation', superclass of 'MYLocation'
for below code

```
@interface MYLocation : CLLocation // code in MyProject-Swift.h
```

when I just imported

```
#import <MyProject/MyProject-Swift.h>
```

after importing below both, the error is gone.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MyProject/MyProject-Swift.h>
```